# Extract substrings with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am doing an xml-> tsv converion using XSLT 2.0.

### DATA

My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TEI.2 SYSTEM "lemmatizzazione.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="dh.xsl"?>
<root>
  <l>
   <LM lemma="me" catg="SS">I</LM>
   <LM lemma="would" catg="VV">would</LM>
   <LM lemma="like" catg="VV">like</LM>
   <LM lemma="to" catg="VV">to</LM>
   <LM lemma="to have" catg="VV">have,</LM>
 </l>
 <l>
   <LM lemma="this" catg="AD">this</LM>
   <LM lemma="BAD" catg="E">in to</LM>
   <LM lemma="a" catg="E">a</LM>
   <LM lemma="ts" catg="AD">tsv</LM>
   <LM lemma="for" catg="NN">format</LM>,
 </l>
 <l>
   <LM1>
    <LM lemma="but1" catg="x01">but</LM>
    <LM lemma="but2" catg="x02">but</LM>
   </LM1>
   <LM lemma="" catg="">first</LM>
   <LM lemma="" catg="">there are</LM>
   <LM1>
    <LM lemma="rxs" catg="fff">a</LM>
    <LM lemma="tre" catg="ds">a</LM>
    <LM lemma="asq" catg="rt">a</LM>
   </LM1>
   "<LM lemma="few" catg="E">few</LM>
 </l>
 <l>
   <LM>problems</LM>
   <LM>to</LM>
   <LM>solve.</LM>
   <LM>Here</LM>
   <LM>and</LM>
 </l>
 <l>
   <LM lemma="there" catg="E">there</LM>.
   <LM lemma="BAD" catg="EE">This is</LM>
   <LM lemma="BAD2" catg="EE">multi word</LM>
   <LM lemma="good" catg="NN">expression.</LM>  
 </l>
</root>
```

### DESIRED OUTPUT

The desired output is the following:

```
token    lemma    catg    l's
I        me       SS      1
would    would    VV      1
like     like     VV      1
to       to       VV      1
have     to have  VV      1
,                         1
...
format   for      NN      2
,                         2
but      but1but2 x01x02  3
```

### MY CODE

My actual XSLT is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="LM">
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains(.,' ')">
    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
      <xsl:with-param name="mwe" select="current()"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="matches(substring(.,string-length(.)),'\.|,|;')">
    <xsl:call-template name="remove_punctuation">
      <xsl:with-param name="token" select="."/>
      <xsl:with-param name="mark" select="substring(.,string-length(.))"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:call-template name="ids"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="LM1">
<xsl:value-of select="LM" />
<xsl:call-template name="multi_ids" />
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template name="ids">
<xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="./@lemma"/><xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="./@catg"/><xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::l) + 1"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="multi_ids">
<xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
<xsl:for-each select="LM">
  <xsl:value-of select="./@lemma"/>
</xsl:for-each><xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
<xsl:for-each select="LM">
  <xsl:value-of select="./@catg"/>
</xsl:for-each><xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::l) + 1"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="tokenize">
<xsl:param name="mwe"/>
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize($mwe/.,'\s+')">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/><xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="$mwe/./@lemma"/><xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="$mwe/./@catg"/><xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="count($mwe/../preceding-sibling::l) + 1"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="remove_punctuation">
<xsl:param name="token"/>
<xsl:param name="mark"/>
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize($token/.,$mark)">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>    
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <th>token</th><xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
    <th>lemma</th><xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
    <th>catg</th><xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
    <th>l's</th><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="l">
    <xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### QUESTION

So, I don't know how to do 2 things:

1)how to separate the word from the punctuations

```
<LM lemma="to have" catg="VV">have,</LM>

have     to have  VV      1
,                         1
```

2)how to "tokenize" the text outside the node

```
<LM lemma="for" catg="NN">format</LM>,

format   for      NN      2
,                         2
```

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to fix problems in XML files with regular expressions. The punctuation problem can be fixed with Perl: `perl -pi -e 's%([,.])</LM>$%</LM>\1%'`.

Comment: Have a look into `xsl:analyze-string`, that should solve at least your fist problem.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Anyway, I don't have to do all the work in XSLT so did a first pass to get the file in a tsv format and then did the tokenization in python.