# Split a list of punctuation chars using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, tokenize

### data

I have an xml in the following format:

```
<a>
 <b>this</b>
 <b>is></b>
 <b>ok</b>
 <b>this</b>
 <b>is</b>
 <b>not</b>"!.
</a>
```

### desired output

The desired output is:

```
this
is
ok
this
is
not
"
!
.
```

### specific problem

My problem is: once I capture the punctuation outside the tags using text(), who do I tokenize them?

I am using XSLT 2.0 and I've tried with

```
tokenize(text(),'.')
```

but is not working.

Note: this question derives from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692334/extract-substrings-with-xslt) other problem.

Comment: The comment in the question you linked to suggests to use `analyze-string`, so why don't you use that?

Comment: @MartinHonnen because I figured out tokenize(text(),'.') is the simplest solution for similar problems. It's just in this case that is not working.

Comment: What should happen if you have punctuation inside a `b` element, or text outside it?

Comment: @TimC it need to be separated from the word. I have already solved this other problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string-to-codepoints()` and `codepoints-to-string()` functions as suggested by [@Dimitre Novatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev) in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2782590/2998271), for example :

```
<xsl:template match="b"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a/text()[normalize-space()]">
    <xsl:for-each select="string-to-codepoints(normalize-space(.))">
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:sequence select="codepoints-to-string(.)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

**<kbd>[`Xsltransform Demo`](http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7kW)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
this
is&gt;
ok
this
is
not
"
!
.
```